# How to remove a class from grandfather div

Tags: javascript

I have a code like this. It is here only to show how It works. Problem appears when I want to compare cards. When I click on the first and second card and they are not matched their grandfather div should remove a class which flips a tile. Second thing, I click on the same card twice it will return "win". How to fix this and make this code look clean?

```js
{
  let guesses = [];
  let tries = 0;
  const doubleArrVal = arr => arr.concat(arr);
  const addFlipEffect = (e) => {
    let target = e.currentTarget;
    if (!target.classList.contains("tile--static")) {
      target.classList.add("tile--active");
    }
    return target;
  };
  const addManyListeners = (collection, e, fn) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      collection[i].addEventListener(e, fn, false);
    }
  };
  const randomize = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
  };
  const prepareArray = (ammount) => {
    let imgNames = ["angular", "bootstrap", "css", "foundation", "github", "grunt", "html", "ruby", "jquery", "less", "nodejs", "sass"];
    imgNames = imgNames.slice(0, ammount);
    const doubled = doubleArrVal(imgNames);
    return randomize(doubled);
  };
  const createMarkUp = (id) => {
    const markUp = `<div class="tile  tile--game">
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--front">
      </div>
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--back">
        <img src="img/${id}.svg" alt="${id}" class="tile__img" data-name="${id}">
      </div>
    </div>`;
    return markUp;
  };
  const createCards = (ammount) => {
    const container = document.getElementById("gameContainer");
    const preparedCards = prepareArray(ammount);
    preparedCards.map(card => {
      const cardElement = createMarkUp(card);
      container.innerHTML += cardElement;
    });
    return container;
  };
  // Problem is here 
  const compare = (e) => {
    const userPick = e.currentTarget;
    let image = userPick.querySelector("[data-name]");
    guesses.push(image);
    tries++;
    if (tries === 2) {
      if (guesses[0].dataset.name === guesses[1].dataset.name) {
        console.log("win");
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          guesses[0].parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active");
          guesses[1].parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active");
        }, 500);
      }
      guesses = [];
      tries = 0;
    }
  }
  const startGame = (level) => {
    const gameCards = createCards(4);
    addManyListeners(gameCards.children, "click", addFlipEffect);
    addManyListeners(gameCards.children, "click", compare);
  };
  startGame();
}
```

```html
<div id ="gameContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Snippet does not work (no cards).

Comment: There's just no CSS, but each element is in fact a card.

Comment: @Salketer Exactly

Comment: When I click them: TypeError: guesses[0] is undefined. Seem to be more problems.

Comment: @trincot yes, that's basically why OP asks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a Set for `guesses`, to facilitate the unique selection:

```
  let guesses = new Set;

  //...

  const compare = (e) => {
    const userPick = e.currentTarget;
    let image = userPick.querySelector("[data-name]");
    guesses.add(image);
    if (guesses.size === 2) { // guaranteed to be 2 different images
      if (new Set(Array.from(guesses, guess => guess.dataset.name)).size == 1) {
        console.log("win");
        guesses = new Set;
      } else {
        setTimeout(() => {
          for (let guess of guesses) {
            guess.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active");
          }
          guesses = new Set; // only clear here
        }, 500);
      }
    }
  }
```

If your template would put the `data-name="${id}"` on the grandfather/root `div`, it would all become a bit simpler: then you only have to work with the `div`, not the `img`:

```
  const createMarkUp = (id) => {
    const markUp = `<div class="tile  tile--game"  data-name="${id}">
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--front">
      </div>
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--back">
        <img src="img/${id}.svg" alt="${id}" class="tile__img">
      </div>
    </div>`;
    return markUp;
  };

  //...

  const compare = (e) => {
    guesses.add(e.currentTarget);
    if (guesses.size !== 2) return;
    if (new Set(Array.from(guesses, guess => guess.dataset.name)).size == 1) {
        console.log("win");
        guesses = new Set;
        return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      for (let guess of guesses) {
        guess.classList.remove("tile--active");
      }
      guesses = new Set;
    }, 500);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have any ideas on how to clear this code out a bit?

Comment: I think the code is quite clean. What is it you don't like about it?

Comment: I would replace this line guess.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active"). Is there any way to appeal to the grandfather element?

Comment: If your template would put the `data-name="${id}"` on the grandfather `div`, it would all become a bit simpler: then you only have to work with the `div`, not the `img`: `let image = e.currentTarget;`, ... and no more `parentNode.parentNode.`.

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. One more question please :D How would you prevent from clicking f12 and inspecting elements?

Comment: That is not possible to prevent. It can be made a bit harder by not storing the names in HTML data attributes, but in a Map, keyed by the `div` elements. But a persistent user could even inspect JavaScript variables, although it would still require some insight to see the connection between the values in the Map and the HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is an error of scope. Your timeout uses the variable `guesses` but it is executed in the global scope, where the variable is undefined. So I have used bind, to bind it to the function.

To make sure you have 2 different elements in guesses, simply test them before testing their value.

```js
{
  let guesses = [];
  let tries = 0;
  const doubleArrVal = arr => arr.concat(arr);
  const addFlipEffect = (e) => {
    let target = e.currentTarget;
    if (!target.classList.contains("tile--static")) {
      target.classList.add("tile--active");
    }
    return target;
  };
  const addManyListeners = (collection, e, fn) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
      collection[i].addEventListener(e, fn, false);
    }
  };
  const randomize = (arr) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      const tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
    }
    return arr;
  };
  const prepareArray = (ammount) => {
    let imgNames = ["angular", "bootstrap", "css", "foundation", "github", "grunt", "html", "ruby", "jquery", "less", "nodejs", "sass"];
    imgNames = imgNames.slice(0, ammount);
    const doubled = doubleArrVal(imgNames);
    return randomize(doubled);
  };
  const createMarkUp = (id) => {
    const markUp = `<div class="tile  tile--game">
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--front">
      </div>
      <div class="tile__side  tile__side--back">
        <img src="img/${id}.svg" alt="${id}" class="tile__img" data-name="${id}">
      </div>
    </div>`;
    return markUp;
  };
  const createCards = (ammount) => {
    const container = document.getElementById("gameContainer");
    const preparedCards = prepareArray(ammount);
    preparedCards.map(card => {
      const cardElement = createMarkUp(card);
      container.innerHTML += cardElement;
    });
    return container;
  };
  const compare = (e) => {
    const userPick = e.currentTarget;
    let image = userPick.querySelector("[data-name]");
    guesses.push(image);
    tries++;
    if (tries === 2) {
      if (guesses[0] !== guesses[1] && guesses[0].dataset.name === guesses[1].dataset.name) {
        console.log("win");
      } else {
        setTimeout(((guesses) => {
          guesses[0].parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active");
          guesses[1].parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove("tile--active");
        }).bind(null, guesses), 500);
      }
      guesses = [];
      tries = 0;
    }
  }
  const startGame = (level) => {
    const gameCards = createCards(4);
    addManyListeners(gameCards.children, "click", addFlipEffect);
    addManyListeners(gameCards.children, "click", compare);
  };
  startGame();
}
```

```html
<div id="gameContainer"></div>
```

Comment: I understand, thank you. Can I make this code in compare function look a bit cleaner?